# When does reinterpret_cast modify bits?

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

From the C++ standard:

> 5.2.10.3
>
> The mapping performed by reinterpret_cast might, or might not, produce
>   a representation different from the original value.

I've been trained at this very site to believe and repeat this.  *(Even if it's possibly just trivia)*.  A `reinterpret_cast` from `float*` to `int*` is allowed to produce a different bit pattern.  The only guarantee is that `reinterpret_cast`-ing that result back to `float*` will produce the original bit pattern.

My question:  Does this ever happen?  Is there an existing, real-world platform or CPU or compiler that actually `reinterpret_cast`s to a different bit pattern?  If not, are there any real-world situations where `reinterpret_cast` has *any* runtime overhead?

In all my experience with `reinterpret_cast`, the cast was a directive to the *compiler*, not the *runtime*.

Comment: If there isn't such a platform, then this question will be hard to answer, as I doubt there are people who can confidently say "there is no such platform, I know them all". However, as a purely hypothetical example, there could be a machine, which requires N-byte memory alignment, and has spare bits in pointer values, and would use those bits to encode some extra information, different for `float*` and `int*`. So if standard wouldn't allow changing bit pattern, the cast would be impossible on that architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked on platforms where `char*` was larger than `int*`,
and on platforms where they had a different layout, even though
the size was the same.  Neither of the machines in question are
particularly relevant today, however (although the second, the
PDP-10, *was* one of the more important machines in its heyday).
It's also conceivable that some compilation modes on an Intel in
native mode (or what used to be called native mode) would
"normalize" pointers in a `reinterpret_cast`, or even an
implicit conversion, in order to facilitate address comparisons.
It's also conceivable (although I've not seen it) that such
conversions enforce correct alignment, e.g. a conversion from
`char*` to `int*` might force the 2 low-order bits to 0.  In
practice, however, I don't think, today, that you're likely to
see a `reinterpret_cast` make any changes between data pointer
types.  The issue is more historic.  (But I'm not sure about
modern embedded processors.  From what I understand, many of them
are word addressing, and so if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char)`, they're
likely to need a special format to address `char`.)

Comment: In my limited experience microcontrollers do not change the pointers and instead crash with a bus error when a misaligned pointer is dereferenced. That probably has something to do with being unable to do the transformation with no runtime cost.

Comment: For these situations you mention, "`char*` is larger than `int*`", "native mode pointers must be normalized", "low-order bits must be zeroed" - does that mean that my premise in the question about _round trip_ casting having to produce "the original bit pattern" is wrong?

Comment: @nwp This is the behavior of Sun CC or g++ on a Sparc; it's probably the universal behavior on a machine with byte addressing.  But do all embedded processors have byte addressing?  What about DSPs?  That's where I'm not sure.  A compiler trying to implement 8 bit bytes on a 32 bit DSP without byte addressing will have to put the additional bits to select the byte somewhere outside the normal hardware address.

Comment: @DrewDormann No.  Round trip is only guaranteed if the
intermediate type has less alignment requirements than the end
types; this is not the case for
`char*`->`int*`->`char*`.  And for
`int*`->`char*`->`int*`, the bits that will be forced to
`0` in the intermediate `char*` will be `0` anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Pointers can in principle be different sizes. The largest pointer, if there is any difference (disregarding member pointers, talking about real pointers), is `char*`, since a `char` by definition is a byte and can be anywhere, no alignment. `void*` must be able to represent `char*`.

On a system with `int*` using fewer bits than `char*`, reinterpret-casting in that direction might be a bit risky.

I think with these pointers (heh) you can find this in the standard. It's the requirement about `void*` being large enough for any pointer, and the thing about alignment: the stricter/larger, the fewer bits needed for pointer to that type. But I have not ever heard of any extant system where there is such difference.

---

Standardese regarding `void*` being able to represent `char*`:

C++11 §3.9.2/4:

> **”**
>   A pointer to *cv*-qualified (3.9.3) or *cv*-unqualified `void` can be used
>   to point to objects of unknown type. Such a pointer shall be able to hold any object
>   pointer. An object of type *cv*  `void*` shall have the same
>   representation and alignment requirements as *cv* `char*`

The “any object pointer” implies vaguely that there are different sizes of pointer.

---

Standaredese regarding the alignment of referent:

C++11 §5.2.10/7:

> **”**
>   An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue `v` of type “pointer to `T1`” is converted to the type “pointer to *cv* `T2`”, the result `is static_cast<`*cv* `T2*>(static_cast<`*cv* `void*>(v))` if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types (3.9) and the alignment
>   requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`, or if either type is `void`. Converting a prvalue of type
>   “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment
>   requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer
>   value. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified.

It’s worth noting that later on in the standard there is some support for C-style emulation of class derivation, that apparently contradicts the “any other” at the end above:

C++11 §9.2/20,

> **”**
>   A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a `reinterpret_cast`, points to its
>   initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa.

In this case the two *objects* necessarily have the same alignment, while the previous cited paragraph talked only about alignment of types – but clearly the formal little contradiction is not a practical problem, as I see it.

Comment: I participated in a discussion about the Mill CPU where one of the team member said that Ivan Godard was working on a "floating pointer" representation which would allow to detect *some* out of bounds accesses. In this case, the inner representation (in the CPU) of the pointer would make use of the unused bits to express the range (somehow). It was unclear in the discussion how far they were, and whether this would be accessible outside the CPU, but at the very least they are thinking about it.